# Check if two np arrays have the same tuple inside of them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays with multiple np arrays inside of them containing tuples of points in (x, y).

A1 = array([array[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)..], [array[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)..]])

A2 = array([array[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)..], [array[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)..]])

I want to check if a tuple in one array from A1 exists in an array from A2.
I have tried np.isin(A1[j],A2[j2]) but i get false even if they have common elements. 
If I use np.isin((x1, y1),A2[j2]) i get true for the values separatly but it does not count the element as a tuple, but instead looks for a match of x1 and y2 separately.

```
list1=[(1,2),(2,2),(3,6)]
ar1=np.empty(len(list1), dtype=object)
ar1[:]=list1

list2=[(1,2),(3,2),(5,4)]
ar2=np.empty(len(list2), dtype=object)
ar2[:]=list2
```

I have multiple arrays like ar1 and ar2 inside of two np arrays like A1 and A2

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why don't you just have a normal multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Are these really tuples or are they a custom dtype?

Comment: Can you provide an actual MCVE? As in code that construct a sample array of the exact type and dtype you want to deal with?

Comment: tuples inside of arrays with dtype=object

Comment: I added it in the main question

Comment: Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Look at `np.isin`; it has a special case for `object` dtype arrays.  It isn't doing any fast/fancy compiled code.   I suspect you are better off treating these as lists rather object arrays.

Comment: Okey, do you know a way that might be faster than using lists with tuples ?

Comment: The fast numpy code mostly just works with numeric dtypes.   Operations on object dtype arrays are usually done a list comprehension speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [319]: ar1                                                                                 
Out[319]: array([(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 6)], dtype=object)
In [320]: ar2                                                                                 
Out[320]: array([(1, 2), (3, 2), (5, 4)], dtype=object)
```

with isin:

```
In [325]: np.isin(ar1,ar2)                                                                    
Out[325]: array([False, False, False])
```

I think the relevant part of `isin` is:

```
        mask = np.zeros(len(ar1), dtype=bool)
        for a in ar2:
            mask |= (ar1 == a)
        return mask

In [326]: [ar1==a for a in ar2]                                                               
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[326]: [False, False, False]
```

but let's try a 'broadcasted' comparison (which seems to be handling the tuple equality just fine):

```
In [327]: ar1[:,None]==ar2                                                                    
Out[327]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Object dtype arrays contain references to Python objects, the same Python lists.  And equality tests of the arrays have to use the equality tests of the objects themselves.  This gives a lot generality, but not speed.

===

Converting the arrays to 2d integer dtype:

```
In [329]: arr1=np.stack(ar1)                                                                  
In [330]: arr1                                                                                
Out[330]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 6]])
In [331]: arr2=np.stack(ar2)                                                                  

In [333]: arr1[:,None,:]==arr2[None,:,:]                                                      
Out[333]: 
array([[[ True,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]]])
In [334]: (arr1[:,None,:]==arr2[None,:,:]).all(axis=-1)                                       
Out[334]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Comment: Do you have any tips on how i may solve this with dtype=int32, to maybe structure the data in some other matrix. Thanks

Comment: I added a 2d integer equivalent